# Resetting Buffers in Vim

Tags: vim, buffer, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to reset the alternate buffer in a vim session to what it was previously?

By alternate buffer, I mean the one that is referred to by #, i.e. the one that is displayed when you enter cntl-^.

Say I've got two files open main.c and other.c and :ls gives me:

```
  1 %a   "main.c"              lines 27
  2 #    "other.c"             lines 56
```

Say I open another file, e.g. refer.c, :ls will now give me:

```
  1 %a   "main.c"              lines 27
  2      "other.c"             lines 56
  3 #    "refer.c"             lines 125
```

If I delete the buffer containing refer.c, :ls now shows:

```
  1 %a   "main.c"              lines 27
  2      "other.c"             lines 56
```

But if I do a cntl-^, refer.c will be displayed again!

Is there some way to get vim to reset the alternate buffer back to what it last was automatically? A "history" of alternate buffers?

Or am I stuck with doing a :2 b to reload other.c into the alternate buffer?

Or maybe there is a good reason for this behaviour?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I didn't know about ctrl-^. productivity++, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, "alternate" just means "previous".  So, yes, :b2 (or 2 ctrl-6) is probably the easiest way to change which two buffers will be toggled by ctrl-6.

Also, take a look at the :keepalt command.

Answer (score 2):

As you'll come to expect with Vim, there is an excellent reason for this behaviour. `:bd` (mnemonic for buffer delete) does *not* delete the buffer, per se, it *deletes it from the main buffer list*!

If you try `:ls!` or `:buffers!` you will see it is is still available but with a `u` adjacent to it's buffer number, indicating it is now "unlisted" (that is, unlisted unless you list it with an exclamation mark!).

I'm making it sound as horrible as possible, but as with most of Vim it works once you understand it, and the use of exclamation mark / bang to force the command is consistent.

To get rid of the buffer completely you need to *wipe* it using `:bw`. When you have done that you will still have the same problem, but this time, attempting to switch to the alternate buffer with `CTRL-^` will elicit `No alternate file` (because this time it *really* has gone).

To switch to the file you want, yes, use the buffer number: `:b2`, or whatever the buffer number is of the file you want, and that will establish a new alternate buffer.

I find it's easy to remember buffer numbers or look them up with `:buffers` or `:buffers!` really quickly, and of course changing to them is then quick, but of course there's a range of techniques in Vim for changing buffers, especially including *marks*.

You've also discovered another great Vim feature here, the unlisted buffers. When you're dealing with a few extra files it's sometimes helpful to "delete" them from the `:buffers` list using `:bd`, just to get them out of sight, but although hidden they're not unavailable, and you can check which one you want with `:buffers!` and then `:b<num>` to pull it up, without having to undelete it or anything.

Comment: Good to see you're still around, @RobWells! I suppose you already know this by now, considering how long you've been using Vim since you originally asked the question!